# Alternatives to Layered Texturing Blender 2.73a?

Tags: texturing

I've been unable to get the layered texturing add-on to work with blender 2.73a. I think this is because the update altered some things, thus the add-on broke. Is there a version out there that works or an alternative one I could use?

Thanks